# Using Compodoc for Storybook documentation?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook, compodoc

When we create an Angular Storybook project it asks us if we want to use Compodoc for documentation.

Does this add something to Storybook that's extra or is it just an alternate way of displaying documentation?